# Excel 2016 Data Validation Not Working After Close & Re-Open

Tags: microsoft-excel, data-validation

I'm trying to put some data validation on a column so that when users input an incorrect colour it will flag an error.

I've used

```
=AND(ISERROR(FIND("KOREA GOLD",E:E)),ISERROR(FIND("ABSOLUTE
BLACK",E:E)),ISERROR(FIND("RED CANDY",E:E)),ISERROR(FIND("BLUE CANDY",E:E)))
```

and it works fine during testing but when I save, close and re-open it seems to lose all functionality.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong or how to fix it?

Many thanks

Comment: Was the conditional formatting saved correctly?

Comment: As far as I'm aware.  When I went back in to check the formula in Data Validation nothing had changed, it just wasn't working.  If I re-type the formula it works again, but stops if I save, close and re-open

Comment: Do you happen to have VBA on your file? Do you save your file as xls instead xlsx? Seems silly to ask, but just want to make sure.

Comment: Consider using validation rather than conditional formatting - this is easier to manage and can prevent errors rather than highlighting them - https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=excel+data+validation

Comment: Thanks for replying, I think there has been some confusion, I am using data validation, not conditional formatting.

Comment: Also, file is saved as xlsx and no VBA